# Banner image couldn't be scraped

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape the link to the banner image (bigger image) from this link: `https://allevents.in/pune/filmmaking-workshop/20001033616713` . For that I tried with these two commands both of which returned an empty list.

```
response.xpath('//img[@class="event-banner-image"]/@src').extract()

response.xpath('//*[@class="event-banner-image"]/@src').extract()
```

I am using Scrapy with Python.

Comment: Could you point out what image you want extracted?

Comment: @Granitosaurus : This one: https://cdn-az.allevents.in/banners/2d76d5624f4e4b83155a51d60b3872fb-rimg-w525-h350-gmir.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually several sources for the image you are looking for in page source.

Simply click <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> (may differ on some browsers) to "view page source" and search for your url string.

I found that you can get the image your looking underneath meta tag:

```
$ scrapy shell https://allevents.in/pune/filmmaking-workshop/20001033616713
In : response.xpath('//meta[@property="og:image"]/@content').extract()
Out: ['https://cdn-az.allevents.in/banners/2d76d5624f4e4b83155a51d60b3872fb-rimg-w525-h350-gmir.jpg']
```